# Why am I getting a "No signature of method"" error when running the closure recursion example in the Groovy shell?

Tags: groovy, recursion, closures

I'm trying to experiment with the Groovy closure recursion example from http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN2515-Closures .

I saved the snippet in a file called recursionTest.groovy and loaded it in the shell, but I'm getting a "No signature of method error":

```
// recursionTest.groovy   

def results = [];
{ a, b ->
  results << a
  a<10 && call(b, a+b)
}(1,1)

assert results == [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]


groovy:000> load recursionTest.groovy
===> []
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.call() is applicable for argument types: (groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1) values: [groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@6b7599cc]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), and(java.lang.Boolean), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:1)
        ...
groovy:003>
```

What's going on?

Comment: There's an updated version of that tutorial at http://groovy.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Blocks%2c%20Closures%2c%20and%20Functions for Groovy 1.7.

Comment: As I recall, I think the issue is with the using `def` in the Groovy shell. The solution was to either move the `def` statement to the first line of the closure, or to remove `def` and just have `results = []`, but I don't remember exactly -- it's been a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two problems in your script :

1. In a shell environment you have a certain scope.  The variables that are bound are in the "binding". To get one in the binding you must see to it that it's **NOT DEFINED** before you use it! So no `def results`.  That's not the error that is cast however.
2. The error that *is* cast can be fixed by **naming your closure** recursion.  That combined with not defining the results yields :

-

```
results = []; 

f = { a, b ->   
results << a   
a<10 && call(b, a+b) }(1,1)

assert results == [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a perfect answer for you, but it looks like [GroovySH has some hacks](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2689?focusedCommentId=127239&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-127239) that can screw it up when working with certain Groovy features.

The example code you have works perfectly in `groovyConsole` (which is a graphical editor, and much easier to play around in), as well as running it using `groovy recursionTest.groovy`.

I haven't found a solution that works correctly in the groovy shell, but I wouldn't really recommend using that for learning, anyway.