# grails shell and closures

Tags: grails, groovy

Trying to run the following command in `grails console`:

```
Family.where() {password =~ "%qw%"}
```

A very simple query on a stored object. I'm getting back:

```
    ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: com.babyboom.Family.where() is applicable for argument types: (groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1) values: [groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@34356294]
Possible solutions: where(groovy.lang.Closure), merge(), every(), grep(), merge(com.babyboom.Family), merge(java.util.Map)
```

I understand that the closure I created is a different than the expected one.
Couple of questions:

- Why there are 2 types of closures ?
- Found [Why am I getting a "No signature of method"" error when running the closure recursion example in the Groovy shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101550/why-am-i-getting-a-no-signature-of-method-error-when-running-the-closure-recu) tried it and it didn't help, still getting the same error
- It works well when using grails console

Comment: Is `com.babyboom.Family` a domain class?

Comment: "Why there are 2 types of closures ?" - There aren't 2 types of closures.  I don't know why you think there are and I don't know what you mean by "I understand that the closure I created is a different than the expected one."

Comment: "It works well when using GroovyConsole" - In order for that to query to work in the groovy console you would have to have somehow bootstrapped the Grails environment in that console which would take quite a bit of work.  Is that what you did?

Comment: Is com.babyboom.Family a domain class? - Yes

Comment: When running grails console from my project directory everything gets bootstrap for me

Comment: I am not asking about the grails console. I am asking about the groovy console.  The original question asserts "It works well when using the GroovyConsole".  Are you saying that when you run "grails console" everything works and when you run "grails shell" the problem occurs?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown fixed my question, I meant 'grails console'

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a classloader bug with the grails shell. To reproduce, add dependency to BuildConfig.gradle:

```
runtime "org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.2.RELEASE"
```

then run

```
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.SimpleMapDatastore
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
class Bar {}

class Foo extends GormStaticApi<Bar> {
    Foo() {
        super(Bar, new SimpleMapDatastore(), [], null)
    }
}

def f = new Foo()
```

In grails console yields:

```
Result: Foo@699c0395
```

In grails shell yields:

```
groovy:000> def f = new Foo()
ERROR java.lang.LinkageError:
loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "Foo.$getStaticMetaClass()Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;" the class loader (instance of groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader) of the current class, Foo, and its superclass loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader), have different Class objects for the type ()Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass; used in the signature
```

Comment: And the missing keyword *static* in the error messages is due to GormStaticApi.methodMissing() raising the MissingMethodException without the isStatic flag, a tiny bug in itself.

Comment: First thing would be to properly report this. Your symptom (MissinMethodException) can also easily be reproduced. Whether there is a workaround for now I don't know.